# No module named 'virtualenv.activation.xonsh'

Tags: python, pipenv

I triyed to execute pipenv shell in a new environtment and I got the following error:

```
Loading .env environment variables…
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /home/user/.pyenv/shims/python3.9 (3.9.7) to create virtualenv…
⠋ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv.activation.xonsh'
Error while trying to remove the /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/7t env: 
No such file or directory

Virtualenv location: 
Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.9, but you are using None (/bin/python).
  $ pipenv check will surely fail.
Spawning environment shell (/usr/bin/zsh). Use 'exit' to leave.
```

I tried to remove pipenv, install python with pienv create an alias to python, but anything works.

Any idea, I got the same error in existing environment, I tried to remove all environments folder but nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By github issue, the solution that works was the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-virtualenv
```

Comment: It is unclear _why_ this is the solution though? Seems un-intuitive to install the very package that provides the required dependency?

Answer (score 63):

Removing the `virtualenv` pip package worked for me (on Ubuntu WSL)

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
```

Comment: It works but I had to use:

`pip3.9 uninstall virtualenv`

Other people having multiple python version on their system might encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error when updating from Python 3.7 to 3.9 in my `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
- python = "^3.7"
+ python = "^3.9"
```

The cause for me was that I had not installed `python3.9-venv` yet. Easy:

```
sudo apt install python3.9-venv
```

Check with

```
python3.9 -m venv
```

---

OS: Ubuntu 21.10, so *your* package name might differ

Answer (score 4):

I'm on a Mac (with Homebrew + Pyenv) and unfortunately none of the other solutions helped. It turned out that even though `pipenv` appeared to run ok, the Pipenv install itself was somehow incomplete/corrupted. Doing

```
pip install pipenv
```

fixed it for me. To do a more thorough reinstall if the above doesn't fix it, you can also try

```
pip install --force-reinstall pipenv
```

Comment: Adding to this: I had pipenv installed at the system and user level. Uninstalling both, then force reinstall fixed my issue. I think it had something to do with mismatched dependency versions.